# Process finished with exit code 139

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So i'm trying to run emulator in Android Studio and for some reason i'm getting an error as "Emulator:Process finished with exit code 139(Interrupted by signal 11:sigsegv),i searched a lot,but they all seem to have solutions specific to programming such as python,c++
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Segmentation Fault. It's likely that you're missing some libraries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384916/android-studio-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-sig

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384916/android-studio-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-sig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,i figured out the cause of this problem,i was using a 1st Gen i3 processor with 4 Gigs of RAM,the RAM wasn't sufficient enough to handle the output,i switched to a core i5 3rd Gen Laptop with 8gigs RAM and it runs smoothly

Answer (score 1):

The following steps did the trick for me.

1. Go into your virtual device's settings.
2. Chang "Emulated Performance" from "Automatic" to "Software".