# Android Studio emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My android studio emulator not starting. I'm using Android Studio 3.0 on Ubuntu 17.10

Error - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Comment: this type of errors are mainly due to low configuration of the pc just verify it

Comment: I had the same problem, it turned out I did not restart my computer after upgrading the driver of my graphic card

Comment: @Turtuvshin Byambaa Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: I only had this error with x86 emulators. The arm-based emulators worked as a temporary work-around.

Comment: Known issue in linux OS:Just reboot the system even system update is failure.

Comment: I got this problem after I updated my ubuntu. For me a system restart solved the issue.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I solved it by going into my virtual device's settings and changing "Emulated Performance" from "Automatic" to "Software".

Comment: I realized this was a temporary solution for me. This solution would fix the error but it would crash the simulator in seconds. Further research brought me to my answer.

Comment: This is OK if you don't want play store but when I try to do this on an android device with play store the option to switch is not available.

Comment: for me, this helped me diagnose a problem with my hybrid (Intel/Nvidia) graphics solution in my laptop. I imagine others may be having a similar problem.

Answer (score 21):

I solved this problem by changing my graphics driver from Software and Updates. Head over to Additional Drivers and Use the proprietary and tested one.
Check if it helps. Thanks

Comment: I use GTX 1060 3GB and it worked for me because the operating system needed Nvidia graphics drivers. Thanks, sir!

Comment: How can i do this for Ubuntu?

Comment: Go to Software and Updates and navigate to Additional Drivers, wait a while and set a proprietary driver. I also solved in ubuntu

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 I had luck with [these instructions](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) (In particular the "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" command)

Answer (score 13):

Changing  "Emulated Performance" from "Automatic" to "Software" was a temporary solution for me (I am on Linux btw). The simulator would crash in a few seconds.

Instead this did it for me:

`cd ~/Development/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/
mv libstdc++ libstdc++.bak`

credit: https://cialu.net/android-studio-how-to-solve-emulator-libgl-error-on-ubuntu-systems/

Comment: This solved it for me. The accepted answer had instead left the device hanging even before the boot was complete.

Comment: @agenteo, where should I type those instructions?

Comment: No such file exists on my machine :)

Answer (score 10):

I have this problem to Emulated `Performance = software` doesn't help, because your emulator will be broken and can not be working if your app needs more process...

> I have Ubuntu 18 and install my graphics card Nvidia, and it's solved
>   now

for `ubuntu` you can try it:

For `Nvidia`

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352  "nvidia-352 is an EXAMPLE In my Device"
```

and For AMD

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

more details:

[enter link description here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-install-graphics-card-drivers-in-ubuntu/3228)

Comment: Missing GPU drivers was exactly my problem! Make sure to check this first before you try the other solutions.

Comment: The instructions you link specifically emphasize that 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-352' is an *EXAMPLE*.  There are specific instructions for getting the correct package.  Please correct your post.

Comment: A lot of times NVIDIA drivers fix the issue, but I would recommend people to disregard your apt install because at the time of reading the version commented it may be outdated(it is for your comment), instead each one has to search an up to date article explaining how to install NVIDIA drivers. In ubuntu just do what @daniel-bentes stated

Comment: For me solution was: command: ubuntu-drivers devices , and command: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall source: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 7):

When use Linux spatially Debian and Ubuntu after update card graphic driver or etc. this problem happening often.

So you need just **reboot your OS**

Answer (score 5):

Restarting the computer worked for me.

Changing the `Emulated Performance` from `automatic` to `software` made it work, but at least on Ubuntu, that has a poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by simply creating a new virtual device.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the linux video card, to solve in Ubuntu 18 or derivatives, just go to "Programs and Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" and select the proprietary driver of your video card and then restart the computer. It resolved for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error tried starting emulator. I am installing android studio 3.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 and NVIDIAM GF119. In Software and Updates, under Additional Drivers tab, I chose the proprietary tested driver for my Graphic card. Then the emulator works.

Answer (score 0):

Found everyone's solution was not working for me. Updated video card on linux and still had the issue.

What worked was changing the number of processor cores available to the emulator from 4 to 2.

I tried the other solutions, but this makes sense as I have 8 processor cores and may need to have several emulators open.

My current configuration is shown in the attached image [my emulator configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEQsC.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with your graphics card driver, i would recommend doing a clean re-install of the driver if it doesn't fix itself on reboot.

**For flatpak users on linux,** i recommend running "flatpak update" in the terminal to update your GPU dependencies for flatpak (it typically breaks if you update your GPU driver and not flatpak GPU libs), this is what resolved the issue for me.

I made this answer because switching to software rendering isn't really a solution, it's more of a dirty workaround, and will only waste your CPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 and driver install solved the problem.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

After finishing the install, need to reboot.

```
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my emulators were stopping with SEGV. Both on software and hardware graphics. But after looking in `journalctl` it was apperantly SELinux that was blocking the emulator. Here I used the SELinux troubleshooter to add a bypass and after that the emulator booted fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

select this update.work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error using intel graphics on ubuntu 20.04 on a lenovo yoga 260.
I tried lots of answers on stack overflow, and none seemed to work. I could not select 'software' from the gui rather than auto. But then I found this page:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration
And I ran this at the command line and it worked. I don't care if it's slow: at least it doesn't crash.

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator
./emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_30 -gpu swiftshader_indirect
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by changing the permissions for the img files

```
cd /home/[your_user]/.android/avd/[device_name]_API_[API_version].avd
chgrp libvirt *.img
chmod 766 *.img
```

Answer (score -1):

In the SDK Manager, under SDK Tools tab, make sure that you've the latest "Android Emulator".

[image]