# Android Studio Emulator Crash: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0, segmentation-fault

I started using android studio on ubuntu 17.10. I used the application to create a standard android project, and at that time the program loaded everything that was or should be installed. When I click on 'Run' I get the following error:

```
Error - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Some of the solutions on the internet showed the following changes in the Manifest file, but it did not work:

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
android.hardwareaccelerated = "false"
```

I made some special adjustments to make it a solution in AVD. I'm writing properties:

- RAM: 1GB Graph
- Graph: Software GLES 2.0
- Multi-Core CPU (marked): 1

I spent hours trying to solve it, but I could not get a solution, so I'm very happy if you can help. I just want to 'run' a simple android application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384916/android-studio-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-sig)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't solved this, or for anyone else who needs to solve this problem,

I solved it by going into my virtual device's settings and changing

"Emulated Performance" from "Automatic" to "Software".

Comment: "Emulated Performance" option is disable for me. I have installed Android Studio 4.0