# Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Hi guys when i want to start android Emulator this problem is showning on eventlog
    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
I search on this problem on the web,stackoverflow and youtube but i cant fix that.
I tried 
my virtual device's settings and changing "Emulated Performance" from "Automatic" to "Software". and it couldnt help to me.

Comment: Please check that you have the correct graphics drivers installed. Also, check that you are downloading the appropriate emulator image for your pc.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should also try different emulator devices - for example, if you have downloaded the x86 API 28 image, try using a Nexus or Pixel device with that image. I have encountered problems with using certain emulator devices, so that also may help resolve your issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384916/android-studio-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-sig

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384916/android-studio-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-sig)

Answer (score -1):

Google for genymotion from AWS, download it together with virtual box. It's more stable and faster than the default emulator. Follow the steps guide how how to used it.

Comment: Thanks for alternatives solutions but i want to fix that problem. Can i ? meanwhile my os is elementary os 5.0